Change in animation action editor
I have been working on an animation with rigging and inverse kinematics, I animated every part of rigging and had just white dots in animation action editor, for every part of the body. I started working on the file again and noticed that it doesn't look the same anymore. Now my blender file appears to be using quarternions, and dots have become orange, connected with green line, in animation action editor. Does this mean it is still using inverse kinematics or not? I am not so sure what has happened, but i need to know, since i must use IK for my student project. I am also adding the file

It doesn't have anymore constraint, it looks like the actions have been baked

@moonboots can you explain it a bit more to me? can I revert it, and is it still using IK? Sorry for such a dumb question but I am so lost :(


A green line connecting keyframes means they are not using B-spline interpolation.
Inverse kinematics don’t turn into forward kinematics on their own, you’d have to bake them to that, which it appears that, sadly, you did. There is no way to reverse this unless you still have the IK targets animated, or an earlier version of the file with the IK still un-baked. Check the .blend1 file to see if it is the latter. If you have the former, delete the baked keyframes on the bones that aren't IK targets (don't delete the IK target animations you made), and set up the IK constraint again.


Thank you so much :) I'm lucky that I have found an older version, which is unbaked (still no idea how i baked it without intention :D
